# android: choose which activity should be first activity

Tags: android, android-activity, authentication

I have a login screen, that i have successfully deleted from history once the user logs in.

But even now if i press the back buttom, and open the application again, it shows the login screen. How do i ensure that once the user logs in, then the application should only show the home screen?

here is the code that i am using to disable history

`android:noHistory="true"`

i guess i should add an override in the onCreate of my application class?

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        // anything else that we need to do, when app is run.
    }
```

Comment: Can't you on the `OnCreate` of the login activity, check if he's already logged and just crate and `Intent` for the actual home? The history will already be deleted, by what you said.

Comment: I think u need to add a check in the on create method of login screen that whether user is logged in or not. If user is logged in then finish the login activity and start the next activity in the on create method of login screen itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy solution is to add a new activity before the Login/HomeScreen activities. In this activity you check if Login is needed and fire the desired Activity:

```
public class StartupActivity extends Activity {
   public void onCreate() {
     if( loginRequired ) {
       //Start the login activity
     }
     else {
       //Start the home screen activity
     }

     finish();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add method to login activity

```
private void successfulLogin() {
  startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
  finish();
}
```

Login activity will be destroyed.